# How to get the value of JSON element having @ in the name in Karate

Tags: karate

This is my json response

```
{
  "meta": {
 "type": "event-search",
 "@href": "https://<ip>:<port>/SentinelRESTServices/objects/event-search/10c21c52229bfe0545BD7802A74E10398534005056869AAA"
}
}
```

I want to get the value for @href.
When i print meta.type I am able to get the value 'event-search', but same doesn't work for @href.

I tried to escape it using \\ (meta.\\@href) but i got empty value.

Is there a way to escape @ and fetch the value?

Please help!!

Comment: You can use meta['@href'] to get the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the square-bracket JS approach to extract nested properties when there are special characters in the key-names.

Example:

```
* def response = { meta: { '@href': 'foo' } }
* match response.meta['@href'] == 'foo'
```